# perl using backticks times out

Tags: python, perl, timeout, backticks

I have a problem I am hoping someone can help with
I am running a perl script that calls a python script with a set of arguments as below

```
my $outText=`sudo /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/tacms/scriptname.py $pNumber $crnNumber`
```

The scriptname is supposed to process information based on the arguments passed and then give a terminal output which is saved in the variable, outText.
There have been instances where this has failed and I suspect it is a timeout. So how would I increase the timeout period of the backticks

Comment: What does "has failed" means? Could you clarify the "failure"?

Comment: If `$outText` is undefined, check `$?` and `$!` as detailed in the documentation for `system`.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it was the script I was calling so what I did was say that if the results of $outText are null then repeat the whole process else continue...ie

```
my $outText=`sudo /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/tacms/scriptname.py $pNumber $crnNumber`

if ($outText eq ""){
    my $outText=`sudo /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/tacms/scriptname.py $pNumber $crnNumber`;
    //use variable here;
    }
else{
        //use variable here;
        }
```

At least this way my system would retry at least once before it fails. That was the best solution I could come up with. The python script being called was calling a web service in SOAP so sometimes, it would timeout.